# Selenium HTML Runner Error (Multi-Window)

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to execute html tests (recorded with Selenium IDE on firefox) with the following command :

```
$> java -jar /path/to/selenium-html-runner-3.0.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.google.com" "/path/to/test.html" "/path/to/results.html"
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
$> Multi-window mode is longer used as an option and will be ignored.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.validateArgs(HTMLLauncher.java:261)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.mainInt(HTMLLauncher.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.main(HTMLLauncher.java:273)
```

Any ideas of want is wrong here ?

Thanks !

Comment: I know this thread is old, but did you ever figure out a way around this?  I don't get any output after that error.  Tried multiple java versions (8,9), multiple firefox versions (48, 54), and even went back to ss 3.1.0.  Same error.  Seems like I missing something.  I'm on ubuntu 16.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I don't really remember this issue but I think changing the selenium-html-runner version was the solution.
Anyway, I've ended using a js framework named protractor to realize my project
I suggest you have a look to it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug that was fixed in the recently released 3.0.1.